# Spacial regularity of heat equation with zero initial condition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the heat equation with zero Dirichlet boundary condition and zero initial data in time interval $[0,T]$:
$$
\partial_t u-\Delta u=f\;\;\text{in $\Omega$};\quad u(0)=0;\quad u|_{\partial \Omega}=0
$$
If we assume that $f\in L^2H^2(\Omega)$ (where $L^2H^2(\Omega)$ is an abbreviation of the Bochner space norm $L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega)$) and $f(t)\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ for almost every $t$, can we conclude the following estimate?
$$
\|\partial_t u\|_{L^2H^2(\Omega)}\leq C\|f\|_{L^2H^2(\Omega)}.
$$
My idea is to intuitively take operator $\Delta$ on the both side of the original heat equation, thus consider the solution $v$ of the following heat equation
$$
\partial_t v-\Delta v=\Delta f\;\;\text{in $\Omega$};\quad v(0)=0;\quad v|_{\partial \Omega}=0
$$
then let $u=(\Delta)^{-1} v$, $u$ seems to be the solution of the original heat equation and satisfies the estimate above. But it seems something went wrong here, could you help with me with finding the mistake?

Comment: Well, that works apart from the boundary condition; $v$ need not be $0$ on the boundary. If the boundary is smooth enough, you can get around that by flattening the boundary via change of variables, etc.

Comment: Why do you think that something went wrong?

Comment: @cs89 Thanks for your comments so much! I guess something went wrong because I did not see this result in any textbook, so I was not sure whether the deduction above is right.

Comment: @user378654 Thanks for your comments so much!

Comment: I am not sure to understand the other comment. Since $u$ vanishes on $\partial\Omega$, so does $\partial_t u$. Since you assume moreover that $f \in H^1_0$, then using the PDE, $v = \Delta u$ does vanish on the boundary. So nothing looks wrong.

Comment: @cs89 I am also not sure about the other comment.

Comment: I didn't notice the OP assuming $f \in H^1_0$, in which case the argument does seem correct.

Comment: To obtain it is in deed enough to assume that $f\in\mathrm{D}(\Delta_\mathcal{D})= H^{1}_0\cap H^{2}$ (assuming the domain is reasonable (smooth enough/convex, bounded etc.)).

For more informations, in the case OP don't know, such estimates are called parabolic $\mathrm{L}^2$-maximal regularity estimates. Here, we just iterated on the domain of the Dirichlet Laplacian, which commutes with the eq. when everything lie in the said domain.